# How to load ENV variable by Domain wise in same environment in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I used Devise, omniauth-facebook gem.

I need to load different ENV variable for different hosts in the same environment(like production) in the same application. Need to implement `Login with facebook`.

I have two host for same application code :

1) www.abc-domain.com

2) www.xyz-domian.com

My ENV variable ( config/settings.yml ) :

```
production:
  abc-domain-credential:
    facebook_access_key: "ABC_ACCESS_KEY"
    facebook_api_key: "ABC_API_KEY"
  xyz-domain-credential:
    facebook_access_key: "XYZ_ACCESS_KEY"
    facebook_api_key: "XYZ_API_KEY"
```

In my devise.rb file ( config/initializer/devise.rb ) :

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  ...
  ...
  require "omniauth-facebook"
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV_SETTINGS["abc-domain-credential"]["facebook_access_key"], ENV_SETTINGS["abc-domain-credential"]["facebook_api_key"], scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email,name'
  # ===== OR ======
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV_SETTINGS["xyz-domain-credential"]["facebook_access_key"], ENV_SETTINGS["xyz-domain-credential"]["facebook_api_key"], scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email,name'
  ...
  ...
end
```

When I access http://www.abc-domain.com then below env should be load from `settings.yml`

```
abc-domain-credential:
   facebook_access_key: "ABC_ACCESS_KEY"
   facebook_api_key: "ABC_API_KEY"
```

When I access http://www.xyz-domain.com then below env should be load from `settings.yml`

```
xyz-domain-credential:
  facebook_access_key: "XYZ_ACCESS_KEY"
  facebook_api_key: "XYZ_API_KEY"
```

Login with Facebook button :

```
<%= link_to "/users/auth/facebook", "Login With Facebook" %>
```

What I have to do load different ENV variable for both host something like

```
if host == "abc-domain"
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV_SETTINGS["abc-domain-credential"]["facebook_access_key"], ENV_SETTINGS["abc-domain-credential"]["facebook_api_key"], scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email,name'
elsif host == "xyz-domain"
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV_SETTINGS["xyz-domain-credential"]["facebook_access_key"], ENV_SETTINGS["xyz-domain-credential"]["facebook_api_key"], scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email,name'
end
```

in `config/initializer/devise.rb` file

Comment: Where are you hosting? are you using something like heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload both credentials into different keys (as you're doing) and use

```
request.base_url
```

In your Devise controllers To determine the calling domain and use the correct credentials.